# exchange 2013 distribution list - allow all external, but only some internal

Tags: windows, exchange-2013

Is there a way to restrict an exchange distribution list email address to Allow All external, but only "A", "B", and "C" internal?

Answer (score 1):

To allow all external messages and several internal senders, you could check the "**Senders inside and outside of my organization**" in the distribution group's "**delivery management**":

[image]

Then create a transport rule to reject the rest internal senders' messages(Condition: **The recipient is a member of the distribution group** and **the sender is** , action: **Reject the message with the explanation(You could choose to delete the message without notifying anyone)**):
[image]
[image]

After that, the messages which are sent from the several internal users to the DL will be rejected, and these internal users will receive a undeliverable message if you reject messages with an explanation or enhanced status code.

Comment: That's quite a hinky workaround. I like it. Let me give it a try and see if the available settings match my use case.

Comment: Hope everything goes well with you :)

Comment: Hi, i'm here to confirm the progress of your thread, if the issue has been solved, you could mark the best answer to help people who have the same problem. Have a good day:)